# Spring Boot Rabbit MQ Could Not autowire ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Am developing a simple message broker with rabbitmq

Below is the Error am getting of "No Beans of 'Connectionfactory' type found"

[image]

My Code is as below with all the correct importations.

Code

```
package com.producer.demo;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MQConfig {
    public static final String message_queue = "message_queue";

    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(message_queue);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange("message_exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange topicExchange){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue)
            .to(topicExchange)
            .with("routing_key");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging to see Boot's auto configuration report to see why the factory bean is not being declared. If it's just an IDE message and the program runs ok, then ignore it - it just means that the IDE doesn't understand the auto config.

Comment: That looks like an IDE concern, nothing more: it just doesn't see whatever is auto-configured for you. What problem do you have at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring boot manages the Connection, Channel and ConnectionFactory for you. You can specify properties in your **application.properties** file

```
spring.rabbitmq.host= 127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port= 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username= guest
spring.rabbitmq.password= guest
```

The second option is that you can define the required bean in your **MQConfig** configuration file
The below code is an example of the same. **I don’t advise you to customize unless you need to**.

```java
...

@Bean
  public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    return connectionFactory;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Program runs ok but i want to remove the error on IntelliJ.

Comment: In this case, you should change the title of the question and update the description, as this sounds off-topic at this point.